# Issue on Handling button click on samsung Tab-4

Tags: android

I have made an app that is running on all android devices perfectly accept of Samsung Tab-4.
Whenever I click any button my app gets force closed. I am stuck in this problem since many day. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Below is the log-cat message I am getting when I click the button.

```
sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you create a button and call its instance in the activity? There are 2 ways to call a button.

1. Create an instance of button b in you class.
   Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
   Then set a listener on it b.setOnClickListener()...
2. Create a button in xml and add onClick with the function name. Example:     android:onClick="handleButton"
   In you activity class Then create a method handleButton(View v){
   }

Comment: I have implemented both way stated by you, yet i got this force close issue.

Comment: Can you show you work as to how you have implemented to know where the error is.